# Is there a way to schedule a shutdown on an interval from the command line?

Tags: macos, command-line

I need to shut down a Mac every night at 10:00 pm. Does Mac have a scheduler that I should use, or should I defer to `cron`? I'm a Linux user, this was a question asked to me by a friend. I'd like to be able to insert the command from a terminal like I would in Linux:

```
crontab -e
```

or

```
(crontab -l >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && (crontab -l && echo "@reboot do-stuff") | crontab -)
```

What's the best option for doing something from the command line? I'm not exactly too  familiar with OSX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cron` is there for compatibility, but it has been superseded by [`launchd`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html), which does indeed have the ability to schedule events.  You need, in your property list file, a `StartCalendarInterval` key with a value that is a simple a `Hour`/`Minute` pair:

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>22</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>00</integer>
</dict>
```

Comment: Although using `cron` is still perfectly fine.

Comment: Hooray for `cron`!

Answer (score 1):

pmset is the command line utility for the system preferences energy saver schedule section.

```
sudo pmset repeat shutdown MTWRFSU 22:00:00
```

GUI at Apple menu > System Preferences... > Energy Saver > Schedule (button)